# Thread problem with input stream from servlet request

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, inputstream

I have brief understanding on multi threading in Java web apps. However, I came across an issue while developing our android app which communicates with the server via REST.
Our web application is based on Apache Wicket 8.6 and contains additional HttpServlet endpoints. One endpoint is applied while uploading images from the app via post. This works fine as long as I am uploading only one image at a time. If I perform multiple upload requests in my android app in a quick succession (some milliseconds), only the last upload is performed successfully (it is working fine when I put a second break between the uploads). It seems, as if all requests except the last one are missing the image content read from the input stream of the servlet request. Thus, I am guessing, that I am having a threading problem with my servlet. I would appreciate, if someone could guide me in the right direction to solve this issue.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        boolean proceed =true;
    
        Map<String,String[]> parameters = req.getParameterMap();
        if(parameters!=null){
            //read some parameters which specify the request
        }
        if(proceed) {
            InputStream is = req.getInputStream();
            if(is!=null) {
                //The result of this output is 0 for the first requests only for the last request it is 1
                System.err.println("Stream size: "+is.available());
                
                //do something
            }
        }
        //do something....
    }
}
```

I could, of course, write the images in my android app in one request using multipart but still I'd like to make the servlet thread safe for the occasion that it gets two requests at the same time.
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some additional research I discovered, that the input stream is not empty even `is.available()` returns 0 
My problem was something different. I save the uploaded image in a ModeShape repository. The repository session is stored in the wicket application instance. THus, only one ModeSHape repository session exists. When writing the image, it seems as if there was a problem with the ModeShape session. Thus, I put the ModeShape session in a synchronized block and now everything runs fine.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        boolean proceed =true;

        Map<String,String[]> parameters = req.getParameterMap();
        if(parameters!=null){
            //read some parameters which specify the request
        }
        if(proceed) {
            String fileName = req.getHeader("fileName");
            if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(fileName)) {
                InputStream is = req.getInputStream();
                if(is!=null) {
                    //The result of this output is 0 for the first requests only for the last request it is 1
                    System.err.println("Stream size: "+is.available());
                    WicketApplication app=null;
                    try {
                        app = (WicketApplication)Application.get("wicket");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        LOG.error("Error while generating WicketApplication object for project "+project.getName(),e);
                    }
                    if(app!=null) {
                        final Session repoSession = app.getRepoSession();
                        synchronized (repoSession) {
                            //write image to repository
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //do something....
    }
}
```